# Why can't I push to an array in an AngularJS factory?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, push

I have a service setup to get information from my API and append it to an array. But I keep getting an error message when I try to use the push() function.

This is the factory:

```
.factory( 'SurgeryList', function($http, $rootScope) {
    var surgeryListService = {
        days: []
    };

    surgeryListService.getDays = function() {
        return days;
    };

    surgeryListService.nextPage = function() {

        var url = $rootScope.url+'/api/surgeries/day.json?surgery_date='+nextDate+'&access_token='+$rootScope.accessToken+'&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';

        $http.jsonp(url)
            .success(function(response, status, headers, config) {
                days.push(response.day);
            }
        );

        return days;
    };

    return surgeryListService;
})
```

I get this error for the push()

```
TypeError: days.push is not a function
```

I have tried to declare days as both an object and an array

```
days: {}
/
days: []
```

both give the same error.

I also noticed that when I declare days as an array, then use console.log(days). It changes from an array into an object in the nextPage() function.

I have also tried to replace push() with concat(), but that also gives me the "not a function" error.

I can get this working if I used keys to add on the day objects.

```
days[response.day.date_string] = response.day;
```

but I want to use some angular filters which don't work properly when I set up days like that.

edit:

The working code was a slight alteration from pankajparkar's answer. I had to use a temp variable for the push, then concat that onto the service variable

```
var temp = [];
temp.push(response.day);
surgeryListService.days = temp.concat(surgeryListService.days);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `surgeryListService.days` instead of `days` because you initialize the days object inside service `surgeryListService`,

You should refactor your service like the following as there are many mistakes.

**Service**

```
.factory('SurgeryList', function($http, $rootScope) {
    var surgeryListService = {
        days: []
    };

    surgeryListService.getDays = function() {
        return surgeryListService.days;
    };

    surgeryListService.nextPage = function() {

        var url = $rootScope.url + '/api/surgeries/day.json?surgery_date=' + nextDate + '&access_token=' + $rootScope.accessToken + '&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';

        $http.jsonp(url)
            .success(function(response, status, headers, config) {
                surgeryListService.days.push(response.day);
            });

        return surgeryListService.days;
    };

    return surgeryListService;
})
```

Comment: That was a very quick response, thanks. I'll mark it off as correct after the 10 minute timer is up.

Comment: for some reason I had to do the push via a temp variable to get it to work, I'll edited my question with the working code. But your answer was the main thing wrong with my code.

Comment: @mike do you need any thing else from me? Thanks :)

Comment: No, just wanted to let you know I needed to make a slight change to your answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

it needs to be `surgeryListService.days.push()` instead of  `days.push`

here

```
$http.jsonp(url)
            .success(function(response, status, headers, config) {
               surgeryListService.days.push()(response.day);
            }
        );
```